# different query when database version change

Tags: mysql

I am migrating the data to a new database. When you run the query the result is different in the 2 databases. The original data is the same
Original data:

```
2023-07-04  08:45:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  08:30:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  08:15:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  08:00:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  07:45:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  07:30:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  07:15:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  07:00:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  06:45:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  06:30:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  06:15:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  06:00:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  05:45:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  05:30:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  05:15:00    1019,06
2023-07-04  05:00:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  04:45:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  04:30:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  04:15:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  04:00:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  03:45:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  03:30:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  03:15:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  03:00:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  02:45:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  02:30:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  02:15:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  02:00:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  01:45:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  01:30:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  01:15:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  01:00:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  00:45:00    1019,05
2023-07-04  00:30:00    1019,05
```

Query:

```
(SELECT fecha as fecha_nueva, hora as hora_nueva,  truncate(valor,4) as valor, 0 as caudal FROM datos WHERE tipo_sensor=3 and id_estacion=13 and year(fecha)>='2016' order by fecha desc, hora desc LIMIT 1 ) 
union 
(sELECT t.fecha as fecha_nueva, t.hora as hora_nueva, truncate(valor,4) as valor, 0 as caudal FROM datos t JOIN 
(SELECT MIN(hora) as mints FROM datos where id_estacion=13 and fecha=curdate() and tipo_sensor=3 GROUP BY  HOUR(hora) order by hora desc ) tt ON t.hora = tt.mints where id_estacion=13 and fecha=curdate() and tipo_sensor=3 order by hora desc) order by hora_nueva desc
```

Old database: version 5.5.40-0+wheezy1-log

```
2023-07-04  09:45:00    1019.0570   0
2023-07-04  09:00:00    1019.0579   0
2023-07-04  08:00:00    1019.0574   0
2023-07-04  07:00:00    1019.0570   0
2023-07-04  06:00:00    1019.0560   0
2023-07-04  05:00:00    1019.0542   0
2023-07-04  04:00:00    1019.0514   0
2023-07-04  03:00:00    1019.0546   0
2023-07-04  02:00:00    1019.0546   0
2023-07-04  01:00:00    1019.0509   0
2023-07-04  00:30:00    1019.0495   0
```

New Database: version 10.5.19-MariaDB-cll-lve

```
2023-07-04  08:45:00    1019.0599   0
2023-07-04  08:00:00    1019.0599   0
2023-07-04  07:00:00    1019.0599   0
2023-07-04  06:00:00    1019.0599   0
2023-07-04  05:00:00    1019.0499   0
2023-07-04  04:00:00    1019.0499   0
2023-07-04  03:00:00    1019.0499   0
2023-07-04  02:00:00    1019.0499   0
2023-07-04  01:00:00    1019.0499   0
2023-07-04  00:30:00    1019.0499   0
```